# F# SqlDataProvider, "The type initializer for 'Main' threw an exception.'

Tags: sql, f#, sqlconnection, type-providers

I have been attempting to use the [SqlProvider](https://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider//index.html) type provider on several different databases where I work. In Visual Studio, intellisense for these different DBs (of types MS Access, SQL Server, and an ODBC connection) all work as shown below:

[image: Intellisense working]

I've even tried it on the [Northwind example database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/downloading-sample-databases):

[image: Northwind]

It does not matter the connection I actually choose, they seem to all result in 2 exceptions when the code is actually run:

```
System.TypeInitializationException
  HResult=0x80131534
  Message=The type initializer for 'Main' threw an exception.
  Source=SqlProviderTest2
  StackTrace:
   at Main.main(String[] _arg1) in C:\Users\***\source\repos\SqlProviderTest2\Program.fs:line 29

Inner Exception 1:
TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for '<StartupCode$SqlProviderTest2>.$Main' threw an exception.

Inner Exception 2:
FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.OleDb, Version=4.0.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (0x80131040)
```

How is it possible that the intellisense can detect the DB but not work when the program is actually run? Is there a common fix for this?

(Using Visual Studio 2019 Professional, if that makes a difference.)

Comment: The key to the problem is the Oledb assembly. Can you look at your bin/debug/netcorexx/ folder and check which version is there?  Since it works in VS the assembly must be somwhere in your machine.  Copy it to bin/debug/.. and see what happens.

Comment: `System.Data.OleDb.dll` says it is version 4.700.19.56404 according to its properties in the Debug/netcoreapp3.1 folder

Comment: For the SQL Server project, all 3 of `System.Data.Odbc.dll`, `System.Data.OleDb.dll`, and `System.Data.SqlClient.dll` are present in the netcoreapp folder as well.

Comment: So 4.700 vs 4.0.1.1 huh.  You need to find out where 4.0.1.1 is referenced and get rid of that reference or viceversa.  (Maybe start from a blank VS project, and add one by one of your references).

Comment: I have not been able to find anything referencing 4.0.1.1 in my project, nor have I been able to figure out where the conflicting numbers are coming from in _any_ of my projects across either VS2017 or 2019, both .NET and .NET Core for _any_ of the DB connections.

Comment: Here you can see some discussion how to solve it for Access https://github.com/fsprojects/SQLProvider/issues/654 it involves getting the .net framework (not core) driver dll from the  nuget cache

Comment: And here some discussion how to solve it for SQL https://github.com/fsprojects/SQLProvider/issues/645#issuecomment-639163535

Comment: In lieu of all this fandangling I have decided to go with the `FSharp.Data.TypeProviders` package and `System.Data.SqlDataConnection` as it offers the same functionality for my current usage needs, I will leave the question open for when the issues reach a more stable resolution point.